# Name for random variables with $\pm$ 1 outcomes

Tags: probability, distributions, bernoulli-distribution

We know that Bernoulli random variables are random variables with 0, 1 outcome, is there a name for the random variables with $\pm$ 1 outcomes?

Answer (score 5):

[Rademacher distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_distribution) is the name for $p=1/2$ case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So what to call the general case, biased Rademacher maybe?

Comment: You may call it as biases but I’m not aware of any well-known naming for the general case.